# Plant Identification: Allium Species

Tags: identification, onions, spring-onions

I'd like to ask what plants these are from the left to the right (scientific name would be better)? I bought the left one 2 years ago, and the seller said that it was Welsh onion. However, when I searched in the internet, it does not look like that very much, and it is more closely related to rakkyo. I'd like to ask for confirmation? Also, what is the scientific name for the one in the middle? I"m not sure if it is A. fistolosum? It's commonly bought in our markets here in the Philippines. Thank you!

[image: This is the image I'm referring to:]

[image: Here's another picture of the "Welsh Onion" I supposedly bought:]

[image: And a zoomed version of the supposed "Welsh Onion". Notice that there are bulbs. To add to that, I'm having a hard time identifying due to the absence of flowers for the two years I planted it.]

Answer (score 1):

For the centre one I think you could be right in guessing Allium fistolosum, however it could be Allium schoenoprasum. Sorry I don't know any others.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to grow them and let them flower to be sure of which one is which. Until then there is likely to be an unanswered question